# Get wordpress taxonomy slug name(s) to use as div class

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to mark up my posts using their custom taxonomy slug as the div class so that they can be filtered...

So far what I have displays the taxonomy name but what I need is the slug so I have a nice-space-free-name, I have the below so far outputting the name:

```
<div class="box-item cocktails-box 
<?php $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'cocktail_type', '', ' ', '' ) );
echo $terms_as_text; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_get_post_terms()`. It will return an array of objects instead of echoing a comma delimited list, one of the object parameters being the slug.

Check it out: [`wp_get_post_terms` in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)